# Как реализовать метод listProducts который возвращает все продукты определённого пользователя из регистра продуктов?

Tags: php

Как в классе User реализовать метод который возвращает все продукты определённого пользователя из регистра продуктов?

```
 <?php
namespace lesson2;



class User{
private $name;
private $balance;

function __construct($name,$balance){
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->balance = $balance;
}

public function getName(){
    return $this->name;
}

public function getBalance(){
    return $this->balance;
}

public function __toString(){
    return $this->getName().' ';
}

public function giveMoney($user, $amount){
    if($amount > $this->balance){
        return 'Недостаточно средств!'."<br/>";
    }
    else{
        $this->balance -= $amount;
        $user->balance += $amount;
        return "Пользователь ".$this->name." перечислил ".$amount." пользователю ".$user->name;
    }

}

public function listProducts(){

}

}

abstract class Product
{
private $name;
private $price;
private $owner;
static private $products = array();

function __construct($name, $price)
{
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->price = $price;
}

public function setOwner(User $user)
{
    $this->owner = $user;
}

public static function getProductIterator()
{
    return new class (self::$products) implements \Iterator {
        private  $position = 0;
        private  $array;

        public function __construct($array)
        {
            $this->array = $array;
        }

        public function rewind()
        {
            $this->position = 0;
        }

        public function current()
        {
            return $this->array[$this->position];
        }

        public function key()
        {
            return $this->position;
        }

        public function next()
        {
            ++$this->position;
        }

        public function valid()
        {
            return isset($this->array[$this->position]);
        }
    };

}

public static function registerProduct($product)
{
    if (in_array($product, self::$products, true)) {
        echo 'Введены одинаковые продукты ' . '</br>';
    } else {
        array_push(self::$products, $product);
    }
}
public function __toString(): string
{
    return "Название: " .$this->name . ', Владелец: ' . $this->owner . ', Цена:' . $this->price . ';';
}


}

class Processor extends Product{
private $frequency;
public function __construct($name, $price,$frequency)
{
    parent::__construct($name, $price);
    $this->frequency=$frequency;
}

}

class Ram extends Product{
private $type;
private $memory;
public function __construct($name, $price, $type, $memory)
{
    parent::__construct($name, $price);
    $this -> type = $type;
    $this -> memory = $memory;
}
}
```

///////////////////////////////////////////

```
$prod = new Processor("Intel",4500,3.9);
$user = new User("Maxim",1000);
$prod->setOwner($user);
Product::registerProduct($prod);

$products = Product::getProductIterator();

foreach ($products as $p) {
echo $p ."\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавим в класс `Product` следующий метод:

```
public function getOwner()
{
    return $this->owner;
}
```

Далее реализация метода `listProducts()` в классе `User`

Вариант 1:

```
public function listProducts()
{
    $products = [];
    /**
     * @var Processor $product
     */
    foreach (Product::getProductIterator() as $product) {
        if($product->getOwner()->getName() === $this->getName()) {
            $products[] = $product;
        }
    }

    return $products;
}
```

Вариант 2, через генераторы:

```
public function listProducts()
{
    /**
     * @var Processor $product
     */
    foreach (Product::getProductIterator() as $product) {
        if($product->getOwner()->getName() === $this->getName()) {
            yield $product;
        }
    }
}
```